# The method 'contains' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: contains("3hmL

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to add likes to the comments in my application that I wrote, but (The method 'contains' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: contains("3hmly93fmrojxdlz09lh3dzmjqu2")) I'm getting this error. My codes are as follows what I need to do.

```
Future<void> LikeComment(String postId, String uid, List likes, String commentId) async {
    try {
      if (likes.contains(uid)) {
        await _firestore.collection('posts').doc(postId).collection('comments').doc(commentId).update({
          'likes': FieldValue.arrayRemove([uid]),
        });
      } else {
        await _firestore.collection('posts').doc(postId).collection('comments').doc(commentId).update({
          'likes': FieldValue.arrayUnion([uid]),
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(
        e.toString(),
      );
    }
  }
```

like

```
Row(
              children: [
                LikeAnimation(
                  isAnimating: widget.snap['likes'].contains(myUid),
                  smallLike: true,
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      await FirestoreMethods().LikeComment(
                        myUid,
                        widget.snap['postId'],
                        widget.snap['commentId'],
                        widget.snap['likes'],
                      );
                    },
                    icon: widget.snap['likes'].contains(myUid)
                        ? const Icon(
                      Icons.favorite,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    )
                        : const Icon(
                      Icons.favorite_border,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              ]),
```

Comment: Are you using NNBD (modern) Dart?  I'm not sure how you get a null in the only expression that has "contains", unless the variables are legacy and nullable.

Comment: Yes, I use dart.  I don't have much of an opinion on this.

Comment: I'm asking if you're using modern dart.  Does "dart --version" show greater than 2.12?  Does your pubspec.yaml request an SDK for dart >= 2.12?

Comment: Yes. I use modern dart.  sdk: ">=2.17.1 <3.0.0"

Comment: What line is throwing the error then?  if this: `if (likes.contains(uid)) {` then neither of those variables can be null, and your error makes no sense.

Comment: not sure bt how about doing null check first like `if (likes!=null && likes.contains(uid))`

Comment: I got the same error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to get null from reading snap, try

```dart
 widget.snap['likes']?? [],
```

and

```dart
 isAnimating: widget.snap['likes']!=null && widget.snap['likes'].contains(myUid), 
 icon: widget.snap['likes']!=null && widget.snap['likes'].contains(myUid)
```

Also it is better to null check on others variable

Comment: I got the same error again

Comment: did you change for all contains?

Comment: yes i changed them all

Comment: Can you try commenting others  `contains` and just use one. and include the error log on question

Comment: Now I did what you wrote, the error disappeared, but I can't see the texts I wrote.

Comment: well, you are getting null value.  Check the  top level snippet from where the data is coming , debugging will help you on this process

Comment: I found the solution to the error, now I can see the comments and the like button. But when I press the like button, the firebase id does not update.